# How I can switch off camera in browser when I read a QR code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-applications, qr-code

Firstly sorry for my English.

Well, my problem is this. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode) for read QRcodes in my WebApp. My QR codes contain links to other parts of my application, but when it redirect me, the camera is not turned off because (I think) that is using AngularJS routes. My question is, how I can force to reload the page when it redirect me ? By this way the camera will be turn off.

This is my code for turn on the cámera and read the QR:

```
        app.controller("ReadQRCtrl", function() {
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#reader').html5_qrcode(function(data) {
                 window.location.href ="http://localhost/SCTraker/Application/appIndex#/"+data;
            },
            function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
            }, function(videoError) {
                 console.log(videoError);
            }
         );
      });
  });
```

Comment: try using window.location.replace instead of window.location.href. I'm not sure it will work but it's worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!! It a bug of the library, I uploaded the library to my GitHub: https://github.com/emilioxiri/html5_qrcode

Comment: don't forget to make a pull request to original repo with your fix.